# Chrome dev tools site gets stuck in mobile view when exiting emulation mode

Tags: sharepoint-2010, google-chrome-devtools

When using chrome dev tools to emulate mobile devices, sometimes when toggling emulation from mobile back to desktop the user agent spoofing gets stuck in mobile. I've tried hard cache reset, closing browser completely, restore to default.... but anything I do the site still renders in mobile (even when emulation is turned off).

This happens in Canary, beta, and regular Chrome. 
Also a note i've only seen this happen in Sharepoint.

Anyone know how to resolve? Nothing seems to get the dev tools to change user agent back to default when exiting emulation.

Comment: ever fixed your chrome!?

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried deleting your chrome settings?

- Windows: C:/Users/%username%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data
- Mac OSX: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/
- Ubuntu: ~/.config/chromium/

Also make sure you aren't ZOOMED! Gets ya everytime

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem previously when using dev tools in Chrome to look at mobile resolutions that got me permanently stuck in mobile for SharePoint only. I solved it originally with the recommendation above of deleting my Chrome settings folder, however, that meant I had to sign in again, sync my extensions, etc.

After forgetting that this would happen again, I ran into the same issue, but this time I discovered that if you append the following to your SharePoint URL it will reset this back to non-mobile. I verified that it is not temporary as I have closed my browser, reopened, visited SharePoint, and it still loads in desktop mode.

/?mobile=0

So, you would use your site url, e.g. https://siteurl/?mobile=0

Answer (score 0):

Weird, this just started happening to me. It persists in new tabs and new windows. Only fix is to open DevTools and switch to Responsive mode and then pull it way out. As soon as I turn off Responsive / Mobile view, Chrome snaps right back to a mobile view by default (appears to be iPad size).

The solution for me (so far) was to quit Chrome and open it back up.